# Is it possible to extend SPFieldUrl to have more properties like url or description, to create a custom field type?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, custom-field-type, spfield

Url field type has more than one property : something like url, description. I want to know that how can I extend url field type(or some other field type that have more than one property) to create a custom field type with more than one property?